# Login to a site through facebook with module requests in Python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, facebook-login

I want to login to a site (webnovel.com) through facebook. Here is my Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'
}

with requests.session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)

    homepage=session.get('https://www.webnovel.com')
    loginFb=session.get('https://ptlogin.webnovel.com/login/facebook?appid=900&amp;areaid=1&amp;returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.webnovel.com%2FloginSuccess&amp;auto=1&amp;autotime=0&amp;source=&amp;ver=2&amp;fromuid=0&amp;target=iframe&amp;option=&amp;logintab=&amp;popup=1&amp;format=redirect', allow_redirects=False)
    loginFb2=session.get(loginFb.headers['Location'], allow_redirects=False)
    loginFb3=session.get(loginFb2.headers['Location'], allow_redirects=False)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(loginFb3.text,'html.parser')

    action_url = soup.find('form', id='login_form')['action']
    link=re.search(r'https.*',action_url).group()
    hexInLink=re.findall(r'%[0-9A-Z]{2,2}',link)
    for item in hexInLink:
        link=link.replace(item,bytearray.fromhex(item[1:]).decode())
    action_url=link

    inputs = soup.find('form', id='login_form').findAll('input', {'type': ['hidden', 'submit']})
    post_data = {input.get('name'): input.get('value')  for input in inputs}
    post_data['email'] = 'email'
    post_data['pass'] = 'pass'
    scripts = soup.findAll('script')
    scripts_string = '/n/'.join([script.text for script in scripts])
    datr_search = re.search(r'\["_js_datr","([^"]*)"', scripts_string, re.DOTALL)
    if datr_search:
        datr = datr_search.group(1)
        cookies = {'_js_datr' : datr}
    r=session.post(action_url, data=post_data, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.history[0].url)
```

But i get redirected to the same facebook page without being logged in. Apparently the POST request method doesn't get accepted but i don't know what else to change or what information to add.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check is there `_js_datr` on the first page. I had the same problem and found that there was no
`datr` sometimes.

Also, you can save all pages in a separate file with `loginFb3.text` and `r.text` content for debug

Comment: Both datr and _js_datr had a value yet still no login